# local variable might be referenced

Tags: python, pycharm, scapy

```
pack = IP(dst=target)/ICMP()
resp = sr1(pack, timeout=2)

if resp == None:
 self.output_console ("no response")
elif IP in resp:
 if resp.getlayer(IP).ttl <= 64:
    self.output_console("*"*20)
    os = 'This Pc is using Linux'

else:
    os1 = "This Pc is using Windows"
self.output_console ("ttl value %d => %s"%(resp.getlayer(IP).ttl)+ os)
self.output_console("*"*20)
```

local variable "os" might be referenced can you help me with this

Answer (score 2):

The warning is telling you that by the time you get to this line:

```
self.output_console ("ttl value %d => %s"%(resp.getlayer(IP).ttl)+ os)
```

The name `os` may not be bound to any object yet.  That will be a crash with `NameError`.  It's probably because you used `os` as the name in one branch, and then `os1` as the name in the other branch.

By the way, the canonical method to check whether Linux or Windows is this:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'
```

Comment: i'am using it to get the os by Ip can you give me the solution please.

Answer (score 0):

`os` is a package in the standard library.  It's probably not a good idea to use it as a variable name

Comment: i changed the variable name but the same problem